# Replace fish installed with installer with fish installed using brew

Tags: installation, homebrew, installer

I first installed fish on macos using the installer.  I later installed fish using brew but my system continues to use the version installed using the installer.  How do I replace the existing version with the brew install version without losing all of my customizations?

The "which fish" command shows /usr/local/bin/fish.  I believe the brew installed fish is at /usr/local/Cellar/fish/3.2.1/bin/fish. I have added /usr/local/Cellar/fish/3.2.1/bin/fish to /etc/shell and I have tried "chsh -s /usr/local/Cellar/fish/3.2.1/bin/fish" but neither approach worked.